# How can I undo changes when a SaveChanges() doesn't succeed?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity, undo

How can I undo changes when a SaveChanges() doesn't succeed ?

```
contextObject.Toto.AddObject( new Toto());

try
{
    contextObject.SaveChanges();
}
catch
{
      // Undo changes !
}
```

In this sample, I'd like to remove the new Toto object in memory. I don't want to remove it manually. I'd like to synchronize my contextObject to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft is working on it : [Unable to refresh some items in the ObjectContext](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/513174/unable-to-refresh-some-items-in-the-objectcontext)

Answer (score 0):

[Saving Changes and Managing Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx):

```
try
{
    // Try to save changes, which may cause a conflict.
    int num = context.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("No conflicts. " +
        num.ToString() + " updates saved.");
}
catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
{
    // Resolve the concurrency conflict by refreshing the 
    // object context before re-saving changes. 
    context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, orders);

    // Save changes.
    context.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("OptimisticConcurrencyException "
    + "handled and changes saved");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I haven't any concurrency exception. I just want to undo my changes in memory (the 'AddObject') and so reset the state manager